# No module named 'rec_rc'

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5

I converted QT `.ui` file into `.py` file and when I run it I get this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Desktop\Project\main2.py:14 in <module>
    from ui3 import Ui_Form

  File ~\Desktop\Project\ui3.py:39 in <module>
    import rec_rc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rec_rc'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution if provided by [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301204/importerror-no-module-named-resource-rc), and it seems to be the same error as yours.

> You should have a file called `rec.qrc`, this must be converted to
> `.py`, this or you can do it by executing:

> `pyrcc5 rec.qrc -o rec_rc.py`

Comment: If you think that a question has already been asked (and answered), please use comments to notify about that.

Comment: Thanks, I want sure at all how to reply. Thanks for the advice, I will do from now on.